# When to filter function details in linux perf?

Tags: performance-testing, perf

While using linux `perf` to record a trace using `intel_pt` event it is possible to filter a *particular function (func1)* trace.

```
 perf record -e intel_pt/branch_type=call/u --filter ' filter func1 @ a.out ' -- ./a.out
```

An alternative approach could be:

```
  perf record -e intel_pt/branch_type=call/u -T --switch-events -- ./a.out
```

followed by

```
  perf script --itrace -c | grep 'func1'
```

`--itrace -c` to select only those branches which are function calls.

My question is whether the accuracy of timestamps recorded in the first approach is better than the second approach?

It could be so as while the first approach specifically filter and records a particular function trace, the second approach record all traces.

It could not be so as first approach require a lot more processing while recording the trace (online filtering overhead) whereas in second approach all the filtering is offline.

Comment: ajit, what is your exact cpu model? There are different versions of intel PT hardware.

Comment: The cpu is Xeon gold 6148 @ 2.4 GHz. CPUID GenuineIntel,6,85,4. perf version 3.10.0-693.

Comment: I have also observed that sometimes no or incomplete trace is recorded when **--filter** flag is used. Is it a bug?

Comment: Trace packet log is generated by hardware at very high speed. It is written to preallocated buffer space, and is periodically saved by perf_events kernel subsystem and passed to perf user-space tool to write it to your disk. When generated trace log is huge, there will be many "wakeup to save" events, and some fragments of this log may be lost. With adequate filtering enabled trace log will be smaller and I expect it to be saved more correctly. Check output of `perf record`, it says how much data chunks were lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, filtering can be done at different levels: at hardware, in OS kernel, or in user-space code. For recent versions of Intel Processor Trace (intel_pt) the filtering is done by hardware trace PMU unit:

[Manpage of perf-record](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html)

```
   --filter=<filter>
       Event filter. This option should follow an event selector (-e)
       which selects either tracepoint event(s) or a hardware trace PMU
       (e.g. Intel PT or CoreSight).  ...

       ·   address filters

               A hardware trace PMU advertises its ability to accept a number of
               address filters by specifying a non-zero value in
               /sys/bus/event_source/devices/<pmu>/nr_addr_filters.

               Address filters have the format:

               filter|start|stop|tracestop <start> [/ <size>] [@<file name>]

               Where:
               - 'filter': defines a region that will be traced.
```

So, first approach is better in terms of trace log size. It generates tracing output only for EIP address range of the func1 function, and trace log packets are not generated by hardware for other addresses. Second approach is full tracing which should generate hundreds of megabytes per second for every call executed.

Filter processing is done in hardware, so there is no huge overhead. I think that tracing hardware will not generate any overhead for executing the code outside of filtered address range, and will do some 1-5% overhead of executing the code in the filtered (required) range.

http://halobates.de/blog/p/406 gives link to hardware description [intel sdm vol 3 chapter 35 intel processor trace](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325384-sdm-vol-3abcd.pdf) "35.2.4.3     Filtering by IP"  (there are 4 hardware filtering range registers in Table 35-6. IA32_RTIT_CTL MSR, so up to 4 address ranges can be defined)

> Trace packet generation with configurable filtering by IP is supported if CPUID.(EAX=14H, ECX=0):EBX[bit 2] = 1. Intel PT can be configured to enable the generation of packets containing architectural states only when the processor is executing code within certain IP ranges. If the IP is outside of these ranges, generation of some packets is blocked. ... When ADDRn_CFG is set to enable IP filtering (see Section 35.3.1), tracing will commence when a taken branch or event is seen whose target address is in the ADDRn range. ... Note that some packets, such as MTC (Section 35.3.7) and other timing packets, do not depend on FilterEn.
>
> 35.2.5.5     Filter Enable (FilterEn) Filter Enable indicates that the Instruction Pointer (IP) is within the range of IPs that Intel PT is configured to watch. ... When FilterEn is 0, control flow packets are not generated (e.g., TNT, TIP). However, some packets, such as PIP, MTC, and PSB, may still be generated while FilterEn is clear.

For exact timestamps you should correctly configure intel_pt options. Timestamps in intel_pt tracing mode are generated by hardware as configured at perf record intel_pt options. [Manpage of perf-intel-pt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-intel-pt.1.html) says that there are tsc, mtc, cyc options to get timestamps

```
   tsc Always supported. Produces TSC timestamp packets to provide
   timing information.  ...


   mtc Produces MTC timing packets.

       MTC packets provide finer grain timestamp information than TSC
       packets.  MTC packets record time using the hardware crystal
       clock (CTC) which is related to TSC packets using a TMA packet.

       Support for this feature is indicated by:

       /sys/bus/event_source/devices/intel_pt/caps/mtc

       which contains "1" if the feature is supported and
       "0" otherwise.

       The frequency of MTC packets can also be specified - see
       mtc_period below.


   cyc Produces CYC timing packets.

       CYC packets provide even finer grain timestamp information than
       MTC and TSC packets.  A CYC packet contains the number of CPU
       cycles since the last CYC packet. Unlike MTC and TSC packets,
       CYC packets are only sent when another packet is also sent.
```

Comment: In other words, filtering using **--filter** is done by PMU hardware. It  happens in parallel to application instruction processing on main CPU. So it will not perturb trace timing and hence will produce **more accurate timestamp** log. The second approach of recording complete trace will incur higher overheads. And it is more likely to **perturb recorded timestamp** of a function. Am I correct?

Comment: @ajit, filter option of perf record with intel_pt is implemented by hardware with very little overhead for code execution outside of filter, you are correct. When the trace log is generated, there is 1-5% overhead for CPU instruction processing (as huge amount of data writes are generated by pmu hardware and these writes take away some part of cache/memory bandwidth). Without filter option you ask PMU to generate 100s MBytes per second for all code, slowing down whole program execution; with filter only your region will have 1-5% slowdown. Complete trace is so huge so it will partially lost.